# Show these equations in terms of x and y only - ∅ has to be eliminated. x=sin ∅ +cos ∅ , y=tan ∅ +cot ∅ (hint find x2y)

Tags: trigonometry, math-software

Can anyone do this question?

Show these equations in terms of x and y only - ∅ has to be eliminated. x=sin ∅ +cos ∅ , y=tan ∅ +cot ∅  (hint find x2y)

Comment: Attempting to deface your own question is futile because all posts and actions are permanently visible and searchable on this site.  Your question was reverted.  Keep this in mind the next time you try to solicit answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By expanding $\left[\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi)\right]^2$, you'll find that

$$x^2=1+2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)$$

Multiplying this by $y=\tan(\phi)+\cot(\phi)$ gives

\begin{align*}
x^2 y &=\left[1+2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)\right]\left[\tan(\phi)+\cot(\phi)\right]\\
&= \left[1+2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)\right]\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\cos(\phi)}+\left[1+2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)\right]\frac{\cos(\phi)}{\sin(\phi)}\\
&= \frac{\sin(\phi)}{\cos(\phi)}+2\sin ^{2}(\phi)+\frac{\cos(\phi)}{\sin(\phi)}+2\cos ^{2}(\phi)\\
&= \tan(\phi)+\cot(\phi)+2\\
&= y+2
\end{align*}

so the equation is $x^2 y=y+2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let us find how the problem came into being.

$$y=\tan\phi+\cot\phi=\cdots=\dfrac1{\sin\phi\cos\phi}$$

$$x^2=(\sin\phi+\cos\phi)^2=1+2\sin\phi\cos\phi$$

Please compare the two values of $\sin\phi\cos\phi$ to eliminate $\phi$